# While loop in node.js

Tags: javascript, c#, while-loop

I am trying to convert a C# snippet for a simple while loop to a JavaScript solution. The C# code asks for a input, prints the output, and as long as the input is not 0, continues the question.

For the JavaScript solution, I am using VS Code and the integrated terminal for the JS output using node. As I understand, when using node and the readline method, I can't use while loops? But resort to if and switch case?

This is my C# code:

```
    public void WriteNumbers(int i)
    {
        while(i != 0)
        {
            PrintWriteNumbers();
            break;
        }
    }

    public void PrintWriteNumbers()
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Provide a number: ");
       WriteNumbers(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
    }
```

Can I get this kind of behavior in the terminal with JavaScript or create a html page?

I started to use a html output for my JavaScript, this is code, but it is incomplete:

```
<h2>JavaScript While Loop</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
let text = ""
let num
        while (num !== 0) {
            num = parseInt(prompt("write a number"))
            text += "<br>The number is " + num
            break
        }
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text
</script>
```

It does take in a number and prints it to the screen. What I want to actually do is to print the output to the p tag, and if the input is not 0, initiate the prompt again for a new input, and exit the prompt when it is 0.

Comment: Just remove `break`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your while loop should be written like this,

```
while (num !== 0) {
    num = parseInt(prompt("write a number"))
    if(num === 0) break;
    text += "<br>The number is " + num
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot :) 
But is it correct, that in node, using readline.. while loops don't work properly?

Comment: This link might be useful for you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24464404/how-to-readline-infinitely-in-node-js